# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am trying to run a basic hibernate 5 program using maven. It gives error while creating the Configuration object. What am I missing ? Getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
    at org.spade.utility.HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtility.java:15)
    at org.spade.dao.UserDao.saveUser(UserDao.java:21)
    at org.spade.dao.UserDao.main(UserDao.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.spade</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernateDemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Following are the jars present as Maven dependencies:
[image]

I have seen other answers on SO giving solution for the same problem but none has worked.

Comment: It sees that you're running a demo from somewhere. Could you provide the link for the source code you're using, please? I ran an example from https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-basic-configuration-example-without-hibernatecfgxml and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a server like jboss? If so, it is probably a mismatch version of hibernate.
Try adding scope provided to use server version as follows:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It's a simple java application running on jvm

Comment: Then it could be your Hibernate utility class, because hibernate it is still looking for hibernate.cfg.xml file